# Modelling elliptic curves in Scala

Tags: scala, math, inner-classes

I’m building a small project in Scala to demonstrate the algorithmic basics of elliptic curve cryptography to non-programmers. Performance doesn't matter. Instead, it must be very general and modular, e.g. allow to define different curves over different fields and play around with them. So far I haven't managed to get the structure right.

I’ve got four basic classes: `EllipticCurve`, `Point` (on a curve), `FiniteField`, and `Element` (of a field).

Here are some of the constraints that I’m dealing with:

- It should be possible to add together any two instances of `Element`, but the result depends on the reduction rule stored in a particular instance of `FiniteField` they are elements of.
- It should be possible to add together any two points on the curve, but the result depends on the equation of a particular curve these two points lie on.
- Finally, the addition of points also depends on a particular instance of `FiniteField` over which the point coordinates are manipulated, i.e. `FiniteField` provides the implementation of addition, multiplication, exponentiation, etc.

So far I got the best results with inner classes (`Point` being an inner class of `EllipticCurve` and `Element` an inner class of `FiniteField`). It’s a bit clumsy and I lose several implicit `def`s which I used (alongside my DSL) to instantiate field elements using just integers and a very math-like notation:

```
val x: Element = 1
val y: Element = 23 u + 17   // an element of a degree 2 field extension
```

When `Element` is defined inside `FiniteField`, those implicit methods can't see it anymore.

Given the above constraints, what's the best way to represent the relationships between these four classes?

EDIT: I realise my question is quite vague. Here's an example of how one might use my program to demonstrate the bilinear property of the Weil pairing.

```
// Construct a field with 23^2 = 529 elements, using a root of X^2 + 1 = 0
val fld = new FiniteField(23, 2)

// Define a curve over fld with coefficients -1 and 0
// i.e. y^2 = x^3 - x
val ec = new EllipticCurve(-1, 0, fld)

// Take a point on the curve ec
val p = new Point(2, 11, ec)

// Take another point, not in the subgroup generated by p
val q = new Point(21, 12 u, ec)  // where u^2 + 1 = 0

val result1 = ec.weil(p, q)      // this gives 15 u + 11
val result2 = ec.weil(p * 2, q)  // this gives 8 u + 11

// Verifying the results
val check = (15 u + 11).pow(2)   // this gives 8 u + 11, as required

// ... similarly for ec.weil(p, q * 2)
```

I would prefer to allow defining `Point`s more naturally (e.g. as tuples) without the trailing `ec`. Does Scala allow to pass `ec` to the `Point` constructor in a more clever way? Is there a way to do it implicitly?

Comment: This question is technically too wide. I've started implementing some structures using, spire, shapeless and custom typeclasses and stuck with implementing basic number operation for p^2 Galois field. If you'd posted existing code in some gist, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, but one thought is that if you don't want `Point` to be an inner class of `EllipticCurve`, but you want `Point` to have access to its `EllipticCurve`, how about just having `Point` hold `EllipticCurve` as a field set in `Point`'s constructor: `class Point(..., ec: EllipticCurve)`?

Comment: well https://github.com/non/spire has Fields, but abstract math frightens me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Maybe you could require an implicit `FiniteField` to be in scope, then your operations on `Elements` (as well as the implicits for interop with `Ints`) could pull in this "working" `FiniteField`. Multiplication of `Points` would also need this implicit `FiniteField`. Construction of `EllipticCurve` may or may not need the implicit `FiniteField` depending on how you design things, but obtaining all the `Points` in the group will certainly require the working `FiniteField`.